# Xcode IB can't resize a UILabel -- just shows mickey mouse hand

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, teamviewer

I want to grab the tiny white square and drag it downward, but IB is showing the mickey mouse hand which won't click and drag any of UILabel's tiny squares.

I am remoted into the Mac from Windows through Teamviewer.

Here's what I see.  But there is also the little mickey mouse glove hovering over the square, but ctrl-Print-Screen didn't copy that through TeamViewer.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to zoom in? Also can you post a screenshot

Comment: aheze:  see above,  I don't know how to zoom in.

Comment: Click the `+` button at the bottom-center of the screen, next to the "78%"